# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 5-6: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-3.x, smtp

I tried to simply use python call gmail via `SMTP`.
However, no matter what I tried, it still showed **UnicodeEncodeError**

```
import smtplib
import sys
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
host = "smtp.gmail.com"
port = 587
username = "ppapa@gmail.com"
password = "ppapapxasfsdfsdfsdfsd"

email_conn = smtplib.SMTP(host,port) #call smtp method 
email_conn.ehlo()
```

Error prompts:

```
utf-8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Useemail.py", line 10, in <module>
    email_conn.ehlo()
  File "C:\Users\Lance\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 439, in ehlo
    self.putcmd(self.ehlo_msg, name or self.local_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Lance\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 366, in putcmd
    self.send(str)
  File "C:\Users\Lance\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 351, in send
    s = s.encode(self.command_encoding)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 5-6: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

Comment: your code worked for me, no error found!

Comment: Same here. Your code works perfectly for me in Python 2 & 3. Is it possible that your Anaconda 3.x installation is somehow using older Python 2 code? On another note, using SMTP is no longer the preferred way to send email, and it's way less secure (plain text password!). Recommend you use the Gmail API (http://developers.google.com/gmail/api); made a video to demo how to use it: http://plus.google.com/+GoogleDevelopers/posts/btPaP3VnrGr To learn more about the error itself, I wrote a post about it long ago http://wesc.livejournal.com/1743.html

Comment: Thanks, I found before connecting the gmail , I should press confirmation in my mailbox

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem today.

The problem I found is because my `from_addr` had UTF-8 chars.
You can try to set `email_conn.command_encoding = 'utf-8'` .

Comment: The code in the question doesn't contain a `from_addr`. If indeed it is a [mcve] I'm guessing the `ehlo` sends your local Windows computer name, and that the OP's contained a non-ASCII string.